# Why listView is not correctly displaying my objects?

Tags: android, listview

I have a JSONArray and I want to add all objects to a listView as part of school homework.

As I got the code right now, listView is displaying a reference to the object but not the strings:
[image: Print screen]

I have got the code in gitHub:

https://github.com/tomasfly/ejercicioFinalLottery

I have created 3 packages (model, view, controller) and in my mainActivy I have got a class which extends from AsyncTask and has a the following onPostExecute() method:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        if(s == null) {
            responseText.setText("Error en la solicitud http");
        }
        else {
            try {
                String jsonInterpretado = "";
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
                //jsonInterpretado = jsonArray.toString();
                //jsontxt.setText(jsonInterpretado);
                int largoJson = jsonArray.length();
                String largoArray=Integer.toString(largoJson);
                Log.d(TAG, "la cantidad de objetos en el array es de" + largoArray);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Jugadas jugadas = new Jugadas();
                    jugadas.setDraw_date(json_object.optString("draw_date"));
                    //Log.d(TAG, "draw date" + i + jugadas.getDraw_date());
                    jugadas.setWinnin_numbers(json_object.optString("winning_numbers"));
                    jugadas.setMultiplier(json_object.optString("multiplier"));
                    arrayOfData.add(jugadas);

                /*    String drawdate = json_object.optString("draw_date");
                    String numbers = json_object.optString("winning_numbers");
                    String multiplier = json_object.optString("multiplier");*/
                }

                responseText.setText("Conexion OK");
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                //Log.d(TAG, arrayOfData.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: I think the code from your adapter is more important in this case

Comment: He doesn't use a custom adapter. he passes in a list of objects so that message up top makes sense.

Comment: how you are created adapter object and how you are setting the values to the listview, post adapter object creation.

Comment: ArrayList<Jugadas> arrayOfData = new ArrayList<Jugadas>();
ArrayAdapter adapter; 
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Jugadas>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfData);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply override `toString()` in your Jugadas model.

Otherwise you need to override `getView()` in your adapter and populate the text from there.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Jugadas>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfData){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_vehicle_info, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        final TextView text= (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        final Jugadas item = getItem(position);
        text.setText(item.name()); 
        //item.name() above is just an example. you will do whatever you need to get the string you want from your data instance.
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looking at your code and your comment its easy to see that you are passing an object in and its simply doing a tostring of the object.  Why don't you extract whatever string you want to display the in the object into another array of string perhaps.